# How to set post-title's background-image to post.firstImageUrl in blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I want main page's post snippets' titles appear over the first image of post(if possible titles display only when mouse hovers on featured(first) images).
I have .post.post-body .post-title classes. I think I have to use javascript to change css of the post-title class in the relevant place of the template code. I found the relevant place, but I couldn't make the javascript correctly. Can someone please help me with below to get it work?

```
<script>
document.getElementByClassName('post-title').style.backgroundImage.src ="...........";
</script>

<style type='text/css'>
.post-title { background-repeat: no-repeat;}
</style>
```